# Should this code go inside.ready() or .window.load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing a XML file, after parsing, I want my function, connectPort(source, dest), to connect two boxes together. The layout of my code is the following:

```
<script>
var connectPort = function(src, dest){ //function definition..}
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: someurl.xml,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
       //parsing.. 
       html = ' <div class = "classA"';
       html += ' blah blah blah'; //this is where I do the HTML 
                                  // and display it on the page
       }
    });
 });

 //is this where I should call the function?

$(window).load(function(){  
        var $xml = $(xml);  //Is this the correct call?
        $xml.find('personRepresentation').has('outputId').has('inputId').each(function () {
        var $br = $(this);
        connectPort($br.find('personRepId').text(), $br.find('outputId').text());
        })
        });


</script>
```

the connectPort() function did not work at the current place in the code, it worked before when I had everything as document.write(), not sure if that made a difference.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does your function do? What makes you think that moving it to another place make a difference?

Comment: _"Is this the correct call?"_ No, `xml` is `undefined` in that context. Deprecated `.load()` event  is fired when the window is loaded. You are mixing two unrelated events. You should call your function in the `success` handler.

Comment: Maybe you just move everything out of the load-function to the ajax-calls success-function?

Comment: why is xml undefined ? I think that is the problem

Comment: Because a in ajax means asynchronous.

Comment: @AlexShilman Apart from that `xml` is not a global variable.

Comment: Should I add $.ajax({type: "GET", url:....}) outside the function then

Comment: Just move the `load` function body to the success handler.

Comment: is this line, var $xml = $(xml);  , needed?

Comment: Since you are using jQuery methods, yes.

Comment: Jenny take a look at my answer below. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a in ajax stands for asynchronous. So you should pass xml result into a callback. Try something like this:

```
$(function(){   
var connectPort = function(src, dest){
    console.log(src, dest);
} 
 $.get( 'someurl.xml', function(xml){
 var $xml = $(xml);
 $xml.find('personRepresentation').has('outputId').has('inputId').each(function () {
     var $br = $(this);
         connectPort($br.find('personRepId').text(), $br.find('outputId').text());
        });//end each
}).fail(function() {
   alert( "failed xml get" );
  });  
});//end ready
```

Comment: You mean script tag? then yes.

Comment: the ]) before .fail, where is the opening for [?

Comment: Ahh, sorry typo. Fixed it

Comment: there is no error getting the XML, but it seems like my connectPort function is not doing anything.. strange. I also moved it into document.ready()

Comment: $(function(){}) is the document.ready(), look at your xml output, do something like console.log(xml). Your filtering is off, I think

Comment: Post your xml, i will help you parse it;

Comment: The problem is that I need the page to load first, do the HTML stuff first, then call connectPort(). Does it do this currently?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46254/discussion-between-alex-shilman-and-jenny)